# Convert Json.NET objects to conventional .NET objects without knowing the types

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

How do I convert Json.NET objects to conventional .NET types (`JArray of string` to `List<string>`, `JTokenType=Integer` to `int`, etc.)?
I have found little besides suggestions to use `AutoMapper` or `JToken.ToObject<T>`.
This is good advice when the JSON structure is known at compile time, but I can't create a class to represent unknown data, or specify a conversion when I don't know the underlying type.
Json.NET doesn't have a "ConvertToWhateverIsProbablyMostAppropriate()" member. :)

So why not just enumerate through `JWhatever` objects, leaving them as-is? 
Because I can't pass those types as parameters to (say) Dapper, which doesn't know JToken from [spoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the following method to convert JToken to good old conventional .NET types.
This is more thorough than I need (to handle only a few JTokenTypes), but I extended it for this answer.

Caveat discipulus: This code is untested and may be a poor implementation of the worst possible approach to a problem that doesn't exist.

```
    /// <summary>Converts a Json.Net JToken to a boxed conventional .NET type (int, List, etc.)</summary>
    /// <param name="token">The JToken to evaluate</param>
    public object JTokenToConventionalDotNetObject(JToken token)
    {
        switch(token.Type) {
            case JTokenType.Object:
            return ((JObject)token).Properties()
                .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => JTokenToConventionalDotNetObject(prop.Value));
            case JTokenType.Array:
            return token.Values().Select(JTokenToConventionalDotNetObject).ToList();
            default:
            return token.ToObject<object>();
        }
    }
```

To handle JArrays, my original problem, Json.NET again makes the task simple:

```
    /// <summary>Converts a Json.NET JArray into a List of T where T is a conventional .NET type (int, string, etc.)</summary>
    /// <param name="jArray">Json.NET JArray to convert</param>
    public IList<object> JArrayToList(JArray jArray) {
        return (List<object>)jArray.ToObject(typeof(IList));
    }
```

Input type: `JArray` of `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue` with `JTokenType` of `Integer`

Output: `List<object>` where each object is of type `System.Int64`

I believe that Json.NET's `ToObject` behavior is not always obvious. Given conversion type `<Object>`, it returns either a conventional .NET type  (`long`, `string`) or does nothing at all, e.g. gets and returns `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`, depending on the JTokenType.

---

Edit: Simplified code with @mason's help and with code from the SO question for which mine is marked duplicate. Now that I better understand Json.NET's types work, I see that answer was sufficient.

The salient difference between the answers is only that that this code handles nested arrays/objects.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for the long function in Charles'/your answer. Just use the generic `ToObject` function and use the `object` type parameter.

Complete Example:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string input = "Hello, world!";
            JToken token = JToken.FromObject(input);
            object output = token.ToObject<object>();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

That said, you *should* know what type it is, and I can't really think of a situation where you wouldn't know what type it is and can't convert it to something more appropriate with a more specific type parameter in the call to `ToObject`.

Comment: "`I can't really think of a situation where you wouldn't know what type`"
I get that a lot. Library authors in particular seem to have the same conclusion.

Comment: ToObject<object> does indeed simplify the function, though only for some data types. I originally wrote code to convert JArrays, for which ToObject<object> is not very helpful, and assumed that the same applied for simple data types.Cue lesson about assuming things. :)

Comment: @Charles I'm not a library author, I'm a full stack web developer. What situation are you dealing with where you don't know what the type is?

Comment: The specific code I was working on receives JSON containing updated data for a DB table it knows nothing about. Each item in this data may be for a concrete column in the table or perhaps for a virtual column created through a join which might be an array of any type. While I can detect the DBMS column type, each DBMS has different types and rules and many support custom types. I want to handle this generically.
Most libraries assume I know all about the data involved, hence the note about library authors, not you specifically. Not that I wouldn't do the same -- this is hardly a typical case.

Comment: If you edit your answer to address objects and arrays, I'll mark it as the answer.