# Deserializing `JArray`'s to numerical multidimensional C# arrays

Tags: c#, json, matlab, json.net

I'm receiving **varying** JSONs with nested json objects and json arrays to C# app, and parsing them using `Newtonsoft.JSON`. I'm sending this data to MATLAB app, and want to send it as plain as I can for the MATLAB to parse the `.NET` types to MATLAB correctly.

For that, I convert the `JObject`'s to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`. I use `dynamic` so that the MATLAB will get `int`, `double`, `String` instead of `object` always.

I also convert the `JArray`'s to `object[]` ([using similar `ToObject()` function as in that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659560/convert-json-net-objects-to-conventional-net-objects-without-knowing-the-types)).

What I'm missing is a way to fully convert `JArray`'s to `double[]`, `int[,]`. etc, if they are actually of that type. This will enable the MATLAB to parse them to MATLAB's `double`, `int32`, etc correctly.

Is there a way of achieving this? Can it also be applied to multidimensional arrays?

Clarification: If I'm getting arrays of strings, I don't mind leaving it `object[]`. I mostly care for numeric multidimensional arrays.

**EDIT:**
As MATLAB prefer jagged arrays over multidimensional, so do I :)

**Existing Code:**

I currently expose the following `Struct`-like type to MATLAB, as it's not possible to marshal MATLAB structs to C#:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StructConverter))]
public class Struct
{

    [JsonExtensionData]
    Dictionary<string, dynamic> dict;

    public Struct() => dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    public Struct(Dictionary<string, dynamic> d) => dict = d;
    public string[] GetKeys() => dict.Keys.ToArray();
    public void Set(string key, dynamic value) => dict[key] = value;
    public void SetVector(string key, int[] value) => dict[key] = value;
    public void SetVector(string key, double[] value) => dict[key] = value;
    public dynamic Get(string key) => dict[key];

}
```

Where `StructConverter` is my current converter:

```
public class StructConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return ReadValue(reader);
    }

    private dynamic ReadValue(JsonReader reader)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                return ReadObject(reader);
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                return ReadArray(reader);
            default:
                return reader.Value;
        }
    }

    private dynamic ReadObject(JsonReader reader)
    {
        MatNet.Struct s = new MatNet.Struct();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    string propName = reader.Value.ToString();
                    if (!reader.Read()) throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
                    s.Set(propName, ReadValue(reader));
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    return s;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
    }

    private dynamic ReadArray(JsonReader reader)
    {
        List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                default:
                    list.Add(ReadValue(reader));
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return list.ToArray();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
    }

}
```

I'm able to serialize and deserialize the following, but the arrays are of `object[]` instead of `int[]`, `string[]` and `double[]`:

```
    var d = new MatNet.Struct();
    d.Set("a", new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 });
    d.Set("b", new string[] { "qwer", "tyui", "asdf", "ghjk" });
    d.Set("c", new double[,] { {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 7}, {6, 8} });
    d.Set("d", new MatNet.Struct());
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
    dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MatNet.Struct>(json);
```

Comment: The matlab library functions for parsing string a much better than c#.  So I would look for a method in matlab to convert json to arrays.

Comment: The problem with that is opposite - MALTAB has looser sense of arrays, as `1` is `double` but also `[1]`, meaning I can't marshal `[1]` from MATLAB to C# correctly. I also need to ability to access a specific string from the received JSON in C# before handing it to MATLAB, so it make sense to parse it in C#.

Comment: It would probably help to see some existing code (see [MCVE]) so we can run test cases to identify a solution.

Comment: You're right, I've added my code.

Comment: No reason going from Matlab to c# should be an issue for arrays.

Comment: But it is. if my `Set()` method which MATLAB uses has `object`/`dynamic` parameter, there is no way to pass `[1]`. There is also no way to pass `[[1, 2]]`.